# LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables. All fields are `NOT NULL`.

```
tb_post
    id
    account_id
    created_at
    content

tb_account
    id
    name
```

I want to select the latest post along with the name. Should I use `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`? From my understanding both produce the same results. But which is more correct or faster?

```
SELECT p.content, a.name
FROM tb_post AS p
[INNER or LEFT] JOIN tb_account AS a
ON a.id = p.account_id
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: The only difference would be in the case of `NULL` entries.

Comment: So the question is `which is faster?` or `how to select latest?`, because now your select is incorrect...

Comment: You have a left table and a right table. If you want to get all the entries from the left, even if they don't have a corresponding value in the right table, then use left. Otherwise use inner.

Comment: @engineer In this case there is always a corresponding value in the right (tb_account) table. So which?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: `Inner join` is what you want, but I wouldn't say 1 is more correct than the other. They serve different purposes. I would really recommend reading http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ It seems like you need to get to grips with simple set theory. This question will be really easy to understand after going over a visual explanation of what's happening when you do an inner vs left join.

Answer (score 1):

A LEFT JOIN is absolutely not faster than an INNER JOIN. In fact, it's slower; by definition, an outer join (LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN) has to do all the work of an INNER JOIN plus the extra work of null-extending the results. It would also be expected to return more rows, further increasing the total execution time simply due to the larger size of the result set.

(And even if a LEFT JOIN were faster in specific situations due to some difficult-to-imagine confluence of factors, it is not functionally equivalent to an INNER JOIN, so you cannot simply go replacing all instances of one with the other!)

Better go for INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

**As Per My View The Correct One Is Inner join**

> because it returns resultset that include only matched elements where Left Join Returns all entries from Left Table. In this case I think Inner join returns the only required amount of data to be proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself two questions.

1) Is there any chance that at some point in your application lifetime, there will be posts with an empty or invalid `account_id`?

If not, it doesn't matter.

If yes...

2) Would it be desirable to include posts without an associated account in the result of the query? If yes, use LEFT JOIN, if no, use INNER JOIN.

Comment: 1) If no, use inner join

Comment: It doesn't matter. The result will be the same and there are no additional rows to process.

Comment: You're right - I was under the impression that there was some additional overhead, but it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think speed is very relevant: the difference between them is what they do.

They happen to give the same result in your case, but that does not mean they can be interchanged, because choosing the one or the other still tells the other guy that reads your code something.

I tend to think like this:
INNER JOIN - the two tables are basically ONE set, we just need to combine two sources.
LEFT JOIN - the left tables is the source, and optionally we may have additional information (in the right table).

So if I would read your code and see a LEFT JOIN, that's the impression you give me about your data model.

Comment: I don't think either of the joins carry any reliable indication of your data model.

A left join could imply that you expect accounts to be missing occasionally... and inner join could imply that you expect account to be missing occasionally and want those records filtered out. Different results, but same hint of your data model. The best solution in this case would be use foreign key constraints (if integrity is wanted) and tell the next developer to look there for clues.